# How can we interpret the linear independence of two transformations $T$ and $U$ in $L(V,W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Recently I encountered a question in Friedberg-Insel-Spence which says that if for two non zero linear transformations have trivial intersection of range space,then they are linearly independent in $L(V,W)$.The problem is very easy and nothing is difficult in solving it;but I think it has a deeper significance than it simply looks.How can I interpret the linear independence of two linear transformations in the space $L(V,W)$?What is the geometric interpretation of $2$ transformations having  trivial intersection of their range spaces?

Comment: Intersection is already geometric in nature (picture intersecting e.g. lines and planes in 3D). For only two vectors, linear independence amounts to neither being a scalar multiple of the other, which is a perfectly fine algebraic interpretation for two linear transformations in $L(V,W)$.

Comment: I am looking for a better visualization.

Comment: An interesting related result: if you have a family of functionals on $V$ $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ (i.e. linear maps from $V$ to its scalar field), then another functional $f$ belongs to $\operatorname{span}\{f_1, \ldots, f_n\}$ if and only if $$\operatorname{ker} f \supseteq \bigcap_{i=1}^n \operatorname{ker} f_i.$$I find it a nice way to visualise the linear (in)dependence of functionals, though I don't know how to generalise it to linear maps to larger spaces.

Comment: Two linear transformations are linearly dependent will mean you can get one from the other by composing with a scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two linear transformations are linearly dependent will mean you can get one from the other by composing with a scaling.